# How do you group your test scenarios (' it()' ) in cypress

Tags: cypress

Recently I was able to fulfill my objective to include in my test report under column 'skip', however I noticed that other test that supposed to pass did not appear in test reports.

and this is how I code it:

```
describe('My simple test class',()=>{
   let rr = true
   beforeEach(()=>{
       if(rr == true){
           expect(2).to.equal(2)
           rr = true
       } else {
          rr = false
       }
   })

   it('child1'()=>{
      if(rr == true){
            expect(4).to.equal(4)
        } else {
            cy.end      
        }
      // - - - here i wanted to have some sort of nested or another 'it() depends but I don't know how
   })

   it('not related'()=>{
      expect(5).to.equal(5)
   }) 

})
```

- - now when the assertion I made in beforeEach is passed. on the report it appears in column 'passing' only 2 and that refers to the 2 test cases below, 'child1' and 'not related'.

if the assertion I made in beforeEach is false or not equal then obviously child1 will be skip and it will appear on the report as in column 'Tests' as 2, Failing as 1, and skip as 1  AND NO PASSING, which should have 1 and that should refer to the 'not related' test .

I am new to cypress and I don't know how to efficiently group as such that it will not affect the entire test if do it this way.

```
 it's like this way - -
 parenta - test scenario
   - child1a - test scenario
   - child2a - test scenario
   - child3a - test scenario
parentb - test scenario
   - child1b - test scenario
   - child2b - test scenario
   - child3b - test scenario

so if parenta is by assertion turned into false or bug then all of its child will be skip but if parentb and its child are passed then in reports all should appear as follows:

Tests | Passing | Failing | Pending | Skipped
  8   |    4    |    1    |         |   3

where:
Tests is the total test available parenta + childa + parentb + childb
Passing is the total passed test cases which is the parentb and its child
Failing is 1 which refer to parenta as a test scenario that fails or returned bug
Pending is obviously zero
Skipped is 3 which refers to the child of parenta
```

Answer (score 3):

It might be useful for you to rethink your testing strategy. Using conditional skips is not really helpful to test all your components and test cases reliable. You are running tests, so running them should not break anything and should not do any harm.

You should test positive and negative cases and furthermore run every test case (`it`) completely independend to all the other test cases. Hence there is no point in skipping Test B, when Test A failed. When a test fails and leaves some weird state, clean it up in the `afterEach` lifecycle method. You can read more about the lifecycle methods [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests.html#Hooks).

For organizing your tests it might help you to use nested `describe` blocks:

```js
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('should be some basic test' () => {
    // test something
  });

  describe('someComplexFunctionOfMyComponent', () => {
    it('should act like case A when X', () => {
      // test case A when X
    });
    it('should cat like case B when Y', () => {
      // test case B when Y
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: oh I 'm sorry to not include the describe but I can assure you that it has. What I wrote here was just inside the describe block...

Comment: also yes that is exactly what i meant about it. run independently but there are test cases that are so called child over the parent that when the parent is bug then the child will have to skip. That's why if that happens those that are not belong should run independently. This would have been easy for TestNG annotation using dependsonmethod and it is what i am trying to emulate on cypress

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it more clear what I mean by "nested describe blocks". Also tried to explain why skipping some Test B does not make any sense when Test A fails. You are running just tests.

Comment: yeah I got your point exactly. it's just what supposed to be easy on TestNG framework in selenium here in cypress, it seems you really have to hard code it. first I tried the approach where it actually work that it appear on the skipped test column in reports but when I do it that way like group describe block and one block has this intentionally skip then  the report seems not right it does not show skip. I think it has issues on it. A BIG THANK YOU FOR YOUR RESPONSE